# ajax loader causing content to flicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, svg, absolute

Pretext: I'm using `Ajax` to switch between `SVG` images in an interactive map.

I implemented a loader image into the `Ajax` requests, but every time it fires the old `SVG` completely disappears until the new `SVG` is added (causing the flicker).

The goal is to get the loader image to hover over the old content instead until the new SVG is completely loaded.

AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/doc.php',
    data: { var: var },
    beforeSend:function(){
        $('#container').html('<div class="loader"><img src="loader.gif"/></div>');
    },
    success:function(data){
        $('#container').empty();
        $('#container').append(data);
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.loader {
    height:60px; width:60px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 47%;
}
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is your svg image size?

Comment: each svg has a viewbox size of 930x300

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they are removing and trying to populated at the same time. If you let (data) load then .delay(1000) or what ever number works then target that old image by id you could accomplish that. Another option is this:

```
complete: function(data){
$('#container').append(data).delay(1000).trigger(remove);
};

Function remove(){
$('#container').find('#fooImage').fadeToggle().remove();
};
```

This should be enough time for the new image to load and once that 1 second is up the function 'remove' is triggered.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I've tried the code but keep ending up with errors one way or another :( That's just my lack knowledge with Jquery though